# iOS working with multiple swipe recognizers

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I have right and left swipe recognizers on my view, as well as a table.There is a problem when user  swipes left->right on the table view, table handle them and swipes table content instead of execution of left->right swipe recognizer methods. How do I increase the sensitivity of left->right swipe recognizers?

Here's the code for the recognizers:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight)];

swipeRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];

swipeRecognizer1.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

swipeRecognizer1.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer1];
```

Comment: Post some of your code

Answer (score 1):

You can require one gestureRecognizer to fail before another one is invoked.

```
[lowerPriorityGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:higherPriorityGestureRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help greatly if you let us know whether the view is in/over/under the table rather than saying you have both a view and a table. That matters, alot.

Comment: I have gesture recognizers attached to the View and the table in the View.